# Как создать связь между приложениями на golang в реальном времени?

Tags: сокет, golang, websocket

Добрый день,
Есть сервер и к нему должны подключаться клиенты. Нужно сделать канал и в реальном времени уведомлять сервер/клиентов.
Как сделать websocket соединение, но не между сервером/браузером, а двумя программами на golang?
Либо посоветуйте другую технологию, что б можно было по каналу отправлять json данные?

Спасибо

Comment: Apache Thrift не подходит? https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/go

Answer (score 1):

Ох, вот тут уж раздолье и беспредельщина.

Самый простой способ - использовать RPC (удаленный вызов процедуры), в Go это осуществляется как никогда просто: [examples](https://haisum.github.io/2015/10/13/rpc-jsonrpc-gorilla-example-in-golang/), также можно использовать брокеры, например, [nats](http://nats.io/), у них другая логика - программы обмениваются событиями, следовательно программа может среагировать на него, а может проигнорировать, удобно в случаях, когда на одно событие должно произойти N действий (записать лог, метрики, отправить эл. сообщения, сохранить в бд).

Если собираетесь строить что-то масштабное и на кучу кластеров (микросервисы) советую обратить внимание на: [Micro Toolkit](https://github.com/micro/micro), либо на [RPCX](https://github.com/smallnest/rpcx). Возможности первого сильно выходят за границы обычного RPC запроса, там есть, и rpc, и брокеры, и стриминг, но это сложно. Второе намного проще, обычный rpc, но на кучу кластеров.

В случаях когда, вы точно знаете, где находится ваш клиент\сервер, стандартного RPC встроенного в Go будет выше крыши.